# How to make an internal SMB share available outside of the firewall using an intermediate server

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-share, dfs

Environment:

- Windows 2008 Server at Data Center 1 - call it `Server A`
- Another Windows 2008 Server at DC 2, call it `Server B`
- Fiber link dynamic IP client, connected via VPN to `Server B`, call it `Client A`

`Client A` wants to see shared drives from `Server A`.  `Server A` can't allow everyone through the firewall, so it is configured for `Server B` to access it's shared folders, via firewall hole.  Idea is to map `Server A`s drives on `Server B`, then re-share them for `Client A`.

We know that this is not possible per se.  So, I tried junction points, they don't work with shared drives.  I tried DFS, and found out that:

> When browsing a folder in the namespace, users are not aware that the folder is hosted by multiple servers. When a user opens the folder, the client computer is automatically referred to a server on its site. If no same-site servers are available, you can configure the namespace to refer the client to a server that has the lowest connection cost as defined in AD DS.

Is there any way to get DFS to re-share a network drive?

I am grasping at straws here, and am referring to the last part of above quoted paragraph, how should I configure the DFS mount point so that it doesn't REDIRECT, but RE-SHARE?

EDIT:

`Server B` can't store complete copy of the data from `Server A`, since server a is collecting data at a rate of 100GB/day.

Comment: Dial-up fiber? Huh?? Anyways, start accepting answers before asking more

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking in your last sentence.

Comment: @joeqwerty what about now?

Answer (score 2):

In light of your most recent update and comments, I think that your best bet is to allow connections to `Server A` via VPN access directly. It doesn't make a lot of sense to involve Server B in the mix at all.

There are packages in the Samba 4 release that can potentially do SMB proxing, but I haven't heard of anyone using them with any level of success. You certainly can't do this with any native Windows tool.

---

In light of your updates, this isn't an answer to your question, but it's still good knowledge nonetheless, so I'll leave it.

There are two different DFS technologies: Namespaces and Replication.

### Namespaces

A DFS Namespace allows for multiple file-servers to have the same UNC. For example `\\domain\share` could be backed by `\\server1\share` and `\\server2\share`. The users have no idea, they just connect to `\\domain\share` and are transparently redirected to one of the backing file servers.

You can define what server users are connected to by a number of ways. One of the most common is by what AD Site they are in. If you want your users to access the share on either server transparently by `\\domain\share`, then you want to use DFS Namespaces, but this isn't a complete answer to your problem.

---

### Replication

DFS-R allows for files to replicated (go figure) across multiple servers. If you had `\\server1\share` and `\\server2\share` in a 2-way replication group, then any changes to either share will propagate to the other. If you want your two servers to have the same contents, then you will use this. It can be used independently of a DFS Namespace, but many times it is used in conjunction with it for seamless access to resources based on AD Site or for redundancy/loadbalancing in general.

You're not "resharing" like your question asks how to do, but rather you're keeping an actual copy of everything in both places, including permissions. This is, at a minimum, what you need to accomplish what you're asking.

---

If you choose to use DFS Namespaces *in addition to* DFR-R, then that's up to you and is a design decision. It will certainly simplify access from your users, but is not completely necessary.

**tl;dr** Use DFS-R and maybe DFS Namespaces, but definitely DFS-R.

---

**Edit**: Since it seems that my text wasn't understood clearly, here's a nice picture

[image: Drawing]

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't solve my problem, since Mosh can't ever access Hetzner directly, and Replication isn't a solution since there is too much data to move around.

Comment: @DanielMošmondor After the initial seed, it uses compression and only transfers changed data. You can use robocopy to make a seed of the data initially. How frequently do the files change and how large are the changes? I'm afraid you're not going to find any better solution using SMB. You could do some NFS cross-mounting, but that's a house of card and will be miserable *when* it fails. Not to mention NFS on Windows is trash at best.

Comment: Also, I have no idea what `Mosh` and `Hetzner` are, but if I understood your question correctly, access isn't a problem. The only (potential) problem is the replication across the firewall. Since `Client A` can connect to `Server B`, and `Server A` replicates with `Server B`, `Client A` never needs to communicate directly with `Server A`.

Comment: I can't use replication.  Period.  Hetzner collects several 100GB of data daily, and moving it out isn't feasible, but only upon request.

Comment: @DanielMošmondor That's usually the kind of thing that you would...you know...write in your question. A design constraint like that is kind of a big deal.

Comment: I added that to question - thanks - the question here is aimed for an alternative to DFS or to hacking it somehow...  BTW, I see that you'll edit my question until it fits your answer :)

Comment: I only edited your tags and the title. You can look at the edit history yourself, if you'd like by [clicking the edit time link](http://i.imgur.com/m2lh8.png) I certainly did not change the content of your question at all.